# kdb/q For/Do Loop with multiple variable inputs

Tags: loops, for-loop, kdb

I have a function created below:

```
// Country Date -> Date
// given a country and a date, provides the next business day
// ex. fNextBDay[`US; 2024.02.02] -> 2024.02.05
fNextBDay:{[c; d] ...}
```

I am trying to loop this function so that it gives me the next x number of business days.

I'm able to loop with just one variable:

```
{x; fNextBDay[`US; x]} \ [5; 2024.02.02]
// output: 2024.02.02 2024.02.05 2024.02.06 2024.02.07 2024.02.08 2024.02.09
```

However, I don't know how I can then abstract the country variable. I tried these lines:

```
1. {x y; fNextBDay[x;y]} \ [5; `US 2024.02.02] -> gives me an error at `US
2. {x y; fNextBDay[x;y]} \ [5; (`US;2024.02.02)] -> gives me this error: "Cannot write to handle 5. OS reports: The request is not supported."
3. {x; fNextBDay[x]} \ [5; (`XNSE;2024.02.06)] -> just returns the function's code
```

Does anyone know how I can abstract out both variables in the loop? I'm thinking it's a syntax issue that I'm not getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can project the country variable into the function prior to the iterator `\`, e.g

```
q)fNextBDay:{y+1+`US<>x};
q){x; fNextBDay[y;x]}[;`US]\ [5; 2024.02.02]
2024.02.02 2024.02.03 2024.02.04 2024.02.05 2024.02.06 2024.02.07
q){x; fNextBDay[y;x]}[;`FR]\ [5; 2024.02.02]
2024.02.02 2024.02.04 2024.02.06 2024.02.08 2024.02.10 2024.02.12

or more simply
q)fNextBDay[`US]\[5;2024.02.02]
2024.02.02 2024.02.03 2024.02.04 2024.02.05 2024.02.06 2024.02.07
q)fNextBDay[`FR]\[5;2024.02.02]
2024.02.02 2024.02.04 2024.02.06 2024.02.08 2024.02.10 2024.02.12
```

Comment: How will the function loop know the country when the loop begins? Both the country and date need to be provided beforehand

Comment: Because it's a projection. The country is already fixed to the function. You can read up on projections here
https://code.kx.com/q/basics/application/#projection

Comment: As a good learning practice you should try to understand why you are getting each of the 3 errors in your initial post.

Comment: My intention is not to have the country variable fixed to the function, there should be two variables: country and date

Comment: The country still is a variable, but fundamentally at a certain point that variable is used once (fixed) prior to the loop beginning. The country doesn't change mid-loop as that wouldn't make sense (you won't increment to the next US trading date, then increment that to the next UK trading date). You can still run the projected loop for various inputs like so: ```{fNextBDay[x]\[5;y]}.'((`US;2024.02.02);(`UK;2024.02.02))```

Comment: I believe that terrylynch's solution is correct, but you could add a wrapper function around it if you prefer..............wrapper: { [country; startDate; numDates] fNextBDay[country]\\[numDates; startDate] }; wrapper [`US; 2024.02.02; 5]